# How to clear a player's inventory he has two of the same unstackable item in inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to clear a player's inventory of an unstackable item if they have two of them in their inventory. This is a system to prevent duplication, while at the same time guaranteeing they still have this item and can't get rid of it.

The problem is: using an NBT tag selector for if the player has this item in their inventory only works for one item. Writing another entry within this NBT tag selector (like `{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:example"},{id:"minecraft:example"}]}`) still treats it like one item and using `{id:"minecraft:example",Count:2b}` doesn't work either since these items can't be stacked.

How can I make this work the way I want it to? I'd rather not make 600+ different NBT tag selectors for each combination of possible `{Slot:#b}`'s if I can avoid it.

Comment: "This is a system to prevent duplication" What does that mean? Does some aspect of your map cause items to be duplicated? Then you should fix that instead of fixing the symptoms.

Comment: You can use `/clear @p <item> 0` and then use that result in a `/stats` command. But since I'm not good with `/stats`, I'll let someone else answer, for example IronAnvil.

Comment: You mention `/modifyitem` - are you looking for an answer applicable to 1.12 or 1.13? The answers will be completely different based on the version you're using.

Comment: "This is a system to prevent duplication, 'while at the same time guaranteeing they still have this item and can't get rid of it.' "

Comment: I wrote in that add-on specifically to avoid confusion on this. The thing is, I want them to be able to put the item in chest inventories and throw them on the ground, but there must be one of that item existing in the world at any given moment. I have to give the player the item back if it doesn't exist anywhere, but that's hard to do since players can simply mouse-click pick-up the item in their inventory to have it disappear from both inventory and world.

Comment: I have a couple of answers which demonstrate what Fabian was talking about.  [Here is one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318926/186522) which was about detecting more then 100 of the same items in a players inventory.  [Here is another](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318972/186522) about detecting them to setup a shop.  I am not sure these will help you though as I am not fully sure what you are attempting to do.  As Fabian commented, without really knowing how items are being duplicated, it's hard to try to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I sorted out the problem, but thanks for showing me those links IronAnvil. Items would get duplicated since I always have to make sure the player has a certain item, or is able to get that single item, at any given time, and if players simply click pick-up the item in their inventory to move it to another slot, the system would give them a copy of the item, thinking they lost it. But I managed to sort it out by preventing the item from being destroyed, so I don't have to worry if it doesn't "exist" anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

*DUH.*

All I have to do is merge {Age:0s} with the item I don't want to disappear. Then I have no need to give the player the item back. And if I have no need to give the player the item back, I have no need to worry if I give the player too many.

*DUH.*